# can we transfer sql database backup from one server to another server directly?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, restore

I want to transfer sql database from one server to another server directly, instead taking back up of that database and copy that back up in another server and then restore it.

Please tell me, Is there any way to do it?

Comment: try replication feature of SQL server

Comment: You need to take a backup, unless the database is readonly in which case you can copy the files directly.

Comment: Do you think there should be something easier than backup -> copy/move -> restore? There isn't anything more reliable, that's for sure. Assuming the destination server has @@VERSION >= source server, and edition >= as well (or the database doesn't use any edition-specific features). What about backup/restore makes this an unattractive option for you? Can you describe the actual problem? Right now this sounds like "how can I avoid taking the subway to work?" The answers will depend on a lot of missing information, like how far are you from work, do you have a car, how late are you...

Comment: Can you let us know how you want to use this copy? Is this for disaster recovery, distributing load, QA Environment, etc?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: What's wrong with simply doing a detach from the source server and a re-attach on the target server? That's how the *NorthWind* and *AdventureWorks* sample databases are distributed.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Because a backup is safer. If something goes wrong while you're copying a backup file, you can take another backup. If something happens to the detached database file while it is detached, you now have ***ZERO*** copies of your database. If you say, well, I'm safe because I took a backup just before the detach? Well, then, use the backup. Distribution of sample databases by Microsoft is not the same standard I would use for handling my own databases. For those dbs, something goes wrong, you can just download it again. For your own, Microsoft doesn't have a spare copy for you.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Also, a backup can be taken without disrupting current users of the existing database (we never received a response about the purpose of the copy). You can't do that with detach - you have to make it single_user or otherwise kick everyone out even to be able to detach it.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are pretty limited.

You can create a shell database and then use something like SQL Compare from RedGate to compare the schema and migrate the schema.  Then possibly do a Data Compare to script out the data and migrate it.

Alternatively, you could use the export option in SQL Server to export a bunch of tables which will recreate the tables on the destination.  The downside here is that FKs and other constraints can get muddled.

Another option is to use replication.  Unfortunately, that means you must backup the database and restore it to the destination server.

And then there is the copy database wizard as mentioned by shanky.

My preference is to use backup/restore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy database wizard to copy database from one server to other. It has some limitations please read [This Microsoft Online Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188664.aspx) before proceeding. Internally database would be transferred to destination server and it is much like backup restore only but you manually dont have to take backup and do restore.

If you want Screenshots on how to achieve this you can refer to below link

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/27/sql-server-copy-database-from-instance-to-another-instance-copy-paste-in-sql-server/